# What is the jsonpath for Kubernetes POD status?

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath, kubectl

I couldn't find the status jsonpath when using kubectl. The pod json has a status field but it is an array.

```
kubectl get pods --column=Status:.status[*]
```

There are several elements in the array, how can I select the one for real pod status?

Comment: This is not a very good question, as [a little searching](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jsonpath+kubernetes+pod+status&atb=v73-4_q&ia=web) would have found [this one](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Kubernetes.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index) [and another](https://linux.oreilly.com/learning/kubernetes-kubectl-commands)

Answer (score 9):

1. One must enable jsonpath output, via `kubectl get pods --output="jsonpath={.status}"`, not via `--column`
2. The results were an array because as written `kubectl` is returning all Pods that are in the current namespace. To get a singular Pod status, qualify your request with:
   `kubectl get pod $the_pod_name_here --output="jsonpath={.status}"`
   if you really do want the status of all pods, then `--output="jsonpath={.items[*].status}"` is likely the syntax you were seeking